# __subclasscheck__ calling order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't find much information regarding the calling order of `__subclasscheck__` (and `subclasshook__`). Say, I subclass `UserString` (which inherits metaclass `ABC`):

```
class MyUserString(UserString):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        print("I was called!")
        return True

print(isinstance([], UserString))
```

I got the output:

```
I was called!
True
```

Using PyCharm to trace this execution, I saw that

1. `ABCMeta`'s `__instancecheck__` was first called;
2. The control then transfers to `ABCMeta`'s `__subclasscheck__`
3. `Reversible`'s `__subclasshook__` is then called and returns `NotImplemented`
4. `ABCMeta`'s `__subclasscheck__` is then called again but this time, its `cls` argument is `MyUserString` instead of `UserString` in (2)
5. `MyUserString`'s `__subclasshook__` is eventually called.

Can someone explain steps 2-5? Why does the control transfer from `__instancecheck__` to `__subclasscheck__`? Why is `Reversible`'s `__subclasshook__` called? and why is `__subclasscheck__` called on `MyUserString` in (4)? If I define another class that subclasses `UserString`, say `MyUserString2`, which one would be used as `cls` in (4) first and why?

Comment: Look at `UserString.__mro__()`, at least regarding #3.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. That would explain sort of why `Reversible`'s `__subclasshook__` was called, but what about (4)? Clearly, `MyUserString` is not in `UserString`'s `__mro__`! (Just saw your edit -- Thanks for explaining #3!)